# I'm trying to use concurrent futures for threading, but it seems some of the futures are not returning, they keep running indefinitely

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

```
def parallelize_task_by_thread(func, iterable, workers=4):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:

        future_to_url = {executor.submit(func, i): i for i in iterable}
        result = []
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url, timeout=120):
            response = future.result()
            result.append(response)
        return result
```

In this code some of the futures never return, even after the timeout. I am not able to understand what's wrong here. This code was working just fine few days back.
And because the future is not returning the for loop never stops and thus it just stays like that, no exception or any other stuff happens.

I am primarily using this function to hit my own AWS server API to get the result, and my API always returns without fail, that i have checked and made sure about

I came across a similar problem [here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1595)

Comment: Please show how you use this function.

Comment: I would guess the `func` itself might be important for us to know how to help.If it worked and now does no longer, you should also check your data. If thats some kind of webscrapy things, chances are, the websites no longer as it was or scrapeprotected.

Comment: it's difficult to show that as this function is being called inside a big code.

Comment: I am using this just to hit my AWS server API and get result